# Failing a Jenkins build pipeline based on Sonar Results

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I have created a Jenkins build pipeline and configured SOnar as I described in one of my earlier [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513527/how-to-configure-a-jenkins-pipeline-for-sonarqube-scan/41513615#41513615).

The Console Output for the build provides in it a URL that I am using for checking the results of Sonar Analysis. However, my requirement is that based on the number of defects that Sonar finds, it should fail the Jenkins build if a specific 'x' no. of defects are found. Pls suggest how this can be configured in  the pipeline

Answer (score 5):

You can try to do it directly from you pipeline script:

```
def scannerHome = tool 'SonarQube Scanner';
withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') {
    sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=advant-web -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.exclusions=node_modules/**,build/** -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0.${BUILD_NUMBER}"
}
sleep 10
sh "curl -u user:password -X GET -H 'Accept: application/json' http://localhost:9000/api/qualitygates/project_status\\?projectKey\\=my-project > status.json"
def json = readJSON file:'status.json'
echo "${json.projectStatus.status}"
if ("${json.projectStatus.status}" == "ERROR") {
    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
    error('SonarQube quality gate status of a project is invalid.')
}
```

or in case of upgrade SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins up to 2.61 you can write something like following:

```
...
timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES') {
    def qualitygate = waitForQualityGate()
    if (qualitygate.status != "OK") {
        error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate coverage failure."
    }
}
```

You can read more here: 
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins

Answer (score 1):

You should:

1. configure [Quality Gate](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Gates) on SonarQube server and assign it to the project
2. install [SonarQube Build Breaker Plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker)

---

Consider whether failing jobs is a good solution in your case: https://blog.sonarsource.com/why-you-shouldnt-use-build-breaker/

Answer (score 0):

I've just done this recently. 
So yes - you need:

- configure quality gate
- Ensure that you have build breaker available on your sonar: [Build Breaker](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker)
  `Break the analyzer if the project does not pass its Quality Gate`

Answer (score 0):

For those who still search on it, I was looking for a similar solution especially can be used via Maven. I realized two solutions:

1. You can set `sonar.qualitygate.wait=true`. Then, it will wait quality gate response.
   Final Maven run will be like:

   mvn verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true

> This will only work, If your Sonar Qube Server version is later than 8.1.

Ref: [Sonar Qube Official Documentation](https://github.com/r0bb3n/sonar-quality-gate-maven-plugin)

2. If your version is lower than 8.1, then you can use below maven plugin

   ```
           <plugin>
               <groupId>io.github.r0bb3n</groupId>
               <artifactId>sonar-quality-gate-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>1.1.0</version>
           </plugin>
   ```

Then, you will run the following Maven Command:

```
mvn sonar-quality-gate:check
```

Ref: [Sonar Quality Gate Plugin](https://github.com/r0bb3n/sonar-quality-gate-maven-plugin)